# How can we draw a bounding box in an image without using tools like LabelImg?

Tags: python, python-3.x, conv-neural-network, bounding-box

I am trying to do object detection as a classification problem. So, I need to draw the ground truth bounding boxes for objects in a particular image (data set is created by me) and then pass it to a classification network. If tools like LabelImg is used, it will come as .txt file or a .csv file. I want to see the bounding box of each image when I open an image. How can I draw bounding box in such a way? Is there any such tool or method?

If anyone knows the answer, kindly help me. Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[opencv](https://opencv.org/) can draw rectangles and write text, that should give you high flexibility.

```
#draw background box for text
cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1 + offset), (x1+label_len_x, y1 + offset + label_len_y), classes_box_colors[class_], thickness = -1)
#draw label
cv2.putText(frame, (meta.names[class_]).decode("utf-8"), (x1, y1 + offset), 1, 1, classes_font_colors, 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
```